# How to use Ember.Select to set association IDs

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to use the Ember.Select control to set an association id on a model. However, I can't seem to get the control to bind it's selection to an id attribute instead of the entire model object. Is this by design in the Ember.Select control? I have the following in my template:

```
  {{view Ember.Select
         contentBinding="App.peopleController.content"
         selectionBinding="App.selectedPersonController.personId"
         optionLabelPath="content.fullName"
         optionValuePath="content.id"}}
```

Yet even with explicitly setting selectionBinding to the personId attribute it still seems to be binding to the person object. Full jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/PXVZb/10/

Comment: It looks like this behavior is intended, see https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls/select.js#L37

Comment: Yes, it looks that way but it makes me wonder why the control accepts and optionValuePath parameter... it seems like that parameter has no effect, or at least not in my jsFiddle.

Comment: `optionValuePath` tells the `Ember.Select` view what property holds the value on all of the `<option>` tags created for `Ember.Select`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to bind the selected person to your `App.selectedPersonController` and create a property `personId` which binds to the persons `id`, see http://jsfiddle.net/PXVZb/11/

JS:

```
App.selectedPersonController = Ember.Object.create({
    personIdBinding: 'person.id'
});
```

Handlebars:

```
{{view Ember.Select
       contentBinding="App.peopleController.content"
       selectionBinding="App.selectedPersonController.person"
       optionLabelPath="content.fullName" }}
```